# zlib.h not found while using make

Tags: linux, makefile, compiler-errors, path, zlib

I am trying to compile a program RabbitQCPlus, according to its github directions: https://github.com/RabbitBio/RabbitQCPlus
It needs gcc and zlib which I have installed. (I work on a server, don't have access to root or sudo permission, use conda for all installations).

When I run `make -j4`, it gives the following errors:

```
    The detected gcc version is 11.2.0 

Based on the detected gcc version and cpuflags, it was decided to use the avx2 instruction set to speed up the program

g++ -c src/options.cpp -o obj/options.o -DVec256 -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP -fconstexpr-ops-limit=99000100 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-terminate -Wno-class-memaccess -DNDUBUG -std=c++17 -I./ -I./common -I./include -I./include/huffman -march=native -I./dependencies/thrust-1.17.0 -g -O3 -w -fopenmp
g++ -c src/main_correct_cpu.cpp -o obj/main_correct_cpu.o -DVec256 -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP -fconstexpr-ops-limit=99000100 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-terminate -Wno-class-memaccess -DNDUBUG -std=c++17 -I./ -I./common -I./include -I./include/huffman -march=native -I./dependencies/thrust-1.17.0 -g -O3 -w -fopenmp
g++ -c src/correctionresultoutput.cpp -o obj/correctionresultoutput.o -DVec256 -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP -fconstexpr-ops-limit=99000100 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-terminate -Wno-class-memaccess -DNDUBUG -std=c++17 -I./ -I./common -I./include -I./include/huffman -march=native -I./dependencies/thrust-1.17.0 -g -O3 -w -fopenmp
g++ -c src/Formater.cpp -o obj/Formater.o -DVec256 -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP -fconstexpr-ops-limit=99000100 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-terminate -Wno-class-memaccess -DNDUBUG -std=c++17 -I./ -I./common -I./include -I./include/huffman -march=native -I./dependencies/thrust-1.17.0 -g -O3 -w -fopenmp
In file included from ./include/kseqpp/kseqpp.hpp:4,
                 from ./include/readlibraryio.hpp:6,
                 from ./include/options.hpp:5,
                 from src/options.cpp:1:
./include/kseqpp/gziphelpers.hpp:4:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <zlib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/kseqpp/kseqpp.hpp:4,
                 from ./include/readlibraryio.hpp:6,
                 from ./include/correctionresultoutput.hpp:6,
                 from src/correctionresultoutput.cpp:1:
./include/kseqpp/gziphelpers.hpp:4:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <zlib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/options.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [obj/correctionresultoutput.o] Error 1
In file included from ./include/kseqpp/kseqpp.hpp:4,
                 from ./include/readlibraryio.hpp:6,
                 from ./include/options.hpp:5,
                 from src/main_correct_cpu.cpp:5:
./include/kseqpp/gziphelpers.hpp:4:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <zlib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/main_correct_cpu.o] Error 1
In file included from src/FastxStream.h:18,
                 from src/Formater.cpp:6:
src/FileReader.h:13:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
   13 | #include <zlib.h>//support gziped files, functional but inefficient
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/Formater.o] Error 1
```

I see it says zlib.h: No such file or directory. I googled and found I need zlib devel library installed, so I did that as well. These are the installed zlib programs right now (from `conda list`):

```
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_0    anaconda
zlib-amzn2-aarch64        1.2.7                         5    anaconda
zlib-devel-amzn2-aarch64  1.2.7                         5    anaconda
```

The error is still not resolved. Any help is appreciated.
I am new to linux so I'd appreciate it if your answers were stupid-friendly.

Comment: What is your Linux distribution, and how exactly have you "installed" zlib-devel? What is the output of the command `find /usr -type f -name "zlib.h"`?

Comment: Linux dist: 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 GNU/Linux (Redhat)
I installed both zlib and zlib-devel using **conda install -c anaconda zlib-devel-amzn2-aarch64** and **conda install -c anaconda zlib**.
The output of your command is:  **find: ‘/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d’: Permission denied
find: ‘/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/auditd’: Permission denied
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/include/config/squashfs/zlib.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/include/config/crypto/zlib.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64/include/linux/zlib.h
/usr/include/zlib.h**

Comment: OK.... that very last line (`/usr/include/zlib.h`) says that the include is right where it's supposed to be. Weird. Can you do a `ls -l /usr/include/zlib.h`, just to rule out strange file permissions?

Comment: This is the result: '-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86717 Nov  5  2016 /usr/include/zlib.h'

Comment: If you write `#include "zlib.h"`, `int main() {}` into a file `testprog.c`, and compile that with `g++ testprog.c -o testprog`, do you still get the `zlib.h not found` error?